# xml schema validation problems

Tags: xml

i'm trying to use an xml schema validator, but i get an error message saying "premature end of file" i can not seem to find where this error is. 
here is my xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="orders">
 <xs:element name ="order" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>  
    <xs:element name="case" type="xs:caseColor" >
      <xs:simpleType name="caseColor">
        <xs:restriction base="string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Lemonde" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Strawberry" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Lime" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Blueberry" />
        </xs:restriction> 
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="batteries" type="xs:numOfBat" default = 
"1"> 
      <xs:simpleType name="numOfBat">
        <xs:restriction base="integer">
            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="3" />
            <xs:enumeration value="4" />
        </xs:restriction> 
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="recharger" type="xs:volt"> 
    <xs:simpleType name="volt">
        <xs:restriction base="string">
            <xs:enumeration value="110-120" />
            <xs:enumeration value="220-240" />
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="arm"> 
       <xs:element name ="reaches" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="3" 
type="xs:reach">
         <xs:simpleType name="reach">
            <xs:restriction base = "integer">
              <xs:enumeration value = "50" />
              <xs:enumeration value = "75" /> 
              <xs:enumeration value = "100" />
             </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:element>
    <xs:element name ="camera" type="numOfCam"> 
      <xs:simpleType name="numOfCam">
        <xs:restriction base="string">
            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
        </xs:restriction> 
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name = "speech" type="xs:language">
      <xs:simpleType name = "language">
        <xs:restriction base = "string">
            <xs:enumeration value = "Spanish" />
            <xs:enumeration value = "Chinese" />
            <xs:enumeration value = "English" />
            <xs:enumeration value = "German" />
            <xs:enumeration value = "French" />
         </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the location of the error is saying it's on line -1,-1.

here is my dtd file just in case as well

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE orders [
<!ELEMENT orders (order+)>
<!ELEMENT order (case, batteries, recharger, arm, camera, 
speech)>
<!ELEMENT case (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT batteries (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT recharger (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT arm (reach)>
<!ELEMENT reach (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT camera (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT speech (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

and the error does not say which file the error is coming from. this is the validator in which i am using. http://corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

i guess since i can't use my dtd, here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
  <order>
    <case> Strawberry </case>
    <batteries> 2 </batteries>
    <recharger> 110-120 V </recharger>
    <arm> 2 
       <length> 50 </length>
       <length> 100 </length>
    </arm>
    <camera> 2 </camera>
    <speech> Spanish </speech>
  </order>
  <order>
    <case> Lime </case>
    <batteries> 4 </batteries>
    <recharger> 220-240 V </recharger>
    <arm> 3 
       <length> 75 </length>
       <length> 75 </length>
       <length> 100 </length>
    </arm>
    <camera> 1 </camera>
    <speech> Chinese </speech>
  </order>
  <order>
    <case> Blueberry </case>
    <batteries> 1 </batteries>
    <recharger> 110-120 V </recharger>
    <arm> 2 
       <length> 75 </length>
       <length> 100 </length>
    </arm>
    <camera> 2 </camera>
    <speech> French </speech>
  </order>
</orders>
```

Comment: Could the problem possibly be in your xml file?

Comment: when i validate my xml schema file, the validator only accepts the dtd file and the xml schema file

Comment: The validator you reference is asking for an "XML Schema" and an "XML Instance".  What are you using for that "XML Instance"?

Comment: the xml instance i'm using my dtd file

Comment: A DTD file is not (and never can be) a valid XML instance.  An instance is an XML file whose structure matches that defined by the XSD.

Comment: ok, what file should i use. i only have a  xsd file, and xml file, and a dtd file.

Comment: In the validator, you would enter your XSD file as the "XML Schema", and the XML file as the "XML Instance".  The validator will verify that the XML file complies with the constraints defined by the XSD file.

Comment: when i use the xml file for the xml instance, says data could not be processed

Comment: ok, i got it to work. but i can't seem to figure out this error. it says s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'orders' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: element. i'm not understanding this error.

Answer (score 1):

The XSD Schema is invalid you can't have nested elements like this

```
<xs:element name="orders">
 <xs:element name ="order" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

In fact the schemas has a load of errors in it.
XML Schemas are difficult to work with, its just not practical to write them by hand, I would suggest using a [graphical XML schema editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Xml-Schema-Editor.aspx) like Liquid XML Studio.

Note:
I think you schema should look like this:-

[image: An XML Schema Fixed with Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2012 Developer Edition 10.0.1.3941 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="language">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Spanish" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Chinese" />
            <xs:enumeration value="English" />
            <xs:enumeration value="German" />
            <xs:enumeration value="French" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="numOfBat">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="3" />
            <xs:enumeration value="4" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="numOfCam">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="caseColor">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Lemonde" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Strawberry" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Lime" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Blueberry" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="reach">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="50" />
            <xs:enumeration value="75" />
            <xs:enumeration value="100" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="volt">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="110-120" />
            <xs:enumeration value="220-240" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Orders">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="order" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="case" type="caseColor" />
                            <xs:element name="batteries" type="numOfBat" default="1" />
                            <xs:element name="recharger" type="volt" />
                            <xs:element name="arm" />
                            <xs:element name="reaches" type="reach" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="3" />
                            <xs:element name="camera" type="numOfCam" />
                            <xs:element name="speech" type="xs:language" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```